# How to modify date pipe in angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I had a problem **InvalidPipeArgument**: for safari for time format but I have solved the problem thank to the solution in [InvalidPipeArgument: '2017-12-05 05:30:00 for pipe 'DatePipe' - Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50653248/invalidpipeargument-2017-12-05-053000-for-pipe-datepipe-safari)

now I am using:

```
<mat-cell *cdkCellDef="let payroll"
                  fxFlex="20%"> {{payroll.time | date : 'dd MMM y h:mm:ss a'}}</mat-cell>
```

and in ts file I convert the time string as in solution post:

```
this.cashOutPayrollTableDataSource.data.forEach(key => {
          key.time = key.time.replace(/\s/g, 'T') + 'Z';
        });
```

But I need to make this ts file code in a pipe. The default pipe I used is already ***date pipe*** which is already defined in angular.

How can I move this typescript code into a new custom pipe code ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to create a custom pipe? Start with

```
ng generate pipe myModuleName.myCustomPipe
```

put your logic in the pipe's `transform` method like this:

```
transform(value: string) {
    return value.replace(/\s/g, 'T') + 'Z';
}
```

and use it in templates

```
{{ someItem.time | myCustomPipe }}
```

You can also chain pipes:

```
{{ someItem.time | myCustomPipe | date }}
```